# VS 2010 C++/CLI Solution on Win 7 32-bit works but on Win7 64-bit does NOT

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c++-cli

I had created some C++/CLI solutions of `Winform` type using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 32-bit machine.
I have installed the exact version of Visual Studio 2010 in Windows 7 64-bit machine but when I tried to open the C++/CLI solutions I got this error in the designer mode:
[image]

Comment: Your code runs at design time as well.  Looks like it throws Exception.  Use the DesignMode property to prevent that from happening.

Comment: Could you please explain more? Where can I find `DesignMode` property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved. The 64-bit machine was ready with .NET Framework which is not compatible with VS2010 requirements. I removed the .NET Framework & VS2010 then reinstalled it & then it works fine.